# How to setup JRuby SDK for IntelliJ's Ruby plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, jruby

Under project structure I go "SDKs > Add > JRuby SDK > New local..." so it asks me to find the SDK in the file system.
The problem is, if I select the parent JRuby directory (or any directory) it disables the OK button, if I select jruby.exe it pops up an error "Cannot find Java 1.5 or higher".

I do have java and I can even run a gem from the terminal outside IntelliJ (so I suppose my JRuby knows about my JDK).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your JAVA_HOME env variable is not set.

I had the same problem. I setup JDK7 in IntelliJ, but JRuby did not recognize that JDK and was still complaining "Cannot find Java 1.5 or higher".

Because  I couldn't set JAVA_HOME globally in my system, I set it locally in cmd session and then run IntelliJ from the same cmd session. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For future Reference :
    Just go to JRuby directory select the bin folder and select jruby file , it will enable the "Ok" button.